# Chaining templates in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a very simple input-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STEP-ProductInformation>
   <Products>
      <Product>
          <Values>
            <ValueGroup AttributeID="tec_att_ignore_basic_data_text">
               <Value ID="Y" QualifierID="en-US">Yes</Value>
               <Value ID="Y" QualifierID="de-DE">Yes</Value>
            </ValueGroup>
            <ValueGroup AttributeID="prd_att_description">
               <Value QualifierID="en-US">
                   english text
               </Value>
               <Value QualifierID="de-DE">
                      german text
               </Value>
            </ValueGroup>
         </Values>
      </Product>
   </Products>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

In my XSL transformation, I want to delete every `Value` in the `prd_att_description`-Value group, if there is a `N` in the attribute: `ignore_basic_data_text`.
This works fine so far, but if everything is deleted (so that there are no childs), I want to remove the whole ValueGroup as well.

My approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:key name="lov" match="ValueGroup[@AttributeID='tec_att_ignore_basic_data_text']/Value" use="@QualifierID" />
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ValueGroup[@AttributeID='prd_att_description']/Value[key('lov', @QualifierID)/@ID='Y']"/>
<xsl:template match="ValueGroup[@AttributeID='prd_att_description' and not(Value)]"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It simply isn't removing the empty `<ValueGroup>`. I tried it with counting elements, with normalize-space(), with different templates, with different modes, but without success. I would assume the 2nd template isn't running over the result of the first template.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the current version of XSLT is 3.0, there you could use `xsl:where-populated` as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="lov" match="ValueGroup[@AttributeID='tec_att_ignore_basic_data_text']/Value" use="@QualifierID" />

  <xsl:template match="ValueGroup[@AttributeID='prd_att_description']/Value[key('lov', @QualifierID)/@ID='Y']"/>

  <xsl:template match="ValueGroup[@AttributeID='prd_att_description']">
    <xsl:where-populated>
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't think there is a direct equivalent in XSLT 1/2 but for your use case I think you basically want the empty template for `ValueGroup` as

```
<xsl:template match="ValueGroup[@AttributeID='prd_att_description'][not(Value[not(key('lov', @QualifierID)/@ID='Y')])]"/>
```

and of course keep your

```
<xsl:template match="ValueGroup[@AttributeID='prd_att_description']/Value[key('lov', @QualifierID)/@ID='Y']"/>
```

Comment: Would there be an equivalent for XSLT 2.0 as well? I'm restricted to `1.0` and `2.0` due to working with a 3rd party software, which only offers these two. I adjusted the tags in my OP as well. Still good to know, though

Comment: @DasSaffe, see whether the suggestion in the edit of the answer helps for your particular use case.

Comment: That does work when all Values should be ignored. However, if I have `N` for german and `Y` for english, the `Values` aren't stripped and both are present. Expected output would be to have only the one Value where the ID is set to `N`

Comment: @DasSaffe, perhaps I didn't express that clearly, see the edit.

Comment: that works perfectly fine! I messed up by replacing your suggestion instead of adding it. Thanks!